# Como verificar os erros no aplicativo com android stúdio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, log

espero contar com a compreensão de todos pois sou apenas hobbysta, comecei a aprender android com a versão 2.3.3 do android studio e verificava os erros e Logs através da ferramenta Monitor, mas depois que atualizei para versão 3.0 essa ferramenta sumiu e não consigo mais verificar erros, alguém poderia me dar uma luz por favor?

Comment: A aba agora chama LogCat

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo com sua ajuda localizei aqui, estou me adaptando a essa atualização rsrs.